# XSL - Removing text blocks from string

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have one question regarding xslt. In my input I have strings like:

```
<dxrCardNumber2>[EBERG615] [104699] [104913]</dxrCardNumber2>
```

and I have to remove all brackets and values between the brackets, if they contains a letter.

The result should be:

```
=> <dxrCardNumber2>104699 104913</dxrCardNumber2>
```

The position of the data I have to remove is random. I tried it with tokenize and then I can filter the not relevant entries out. But at teh end I have the problem to combine all entries again in one string.

Comment: Please say which version of XSLT you are able to use. This kind of task is much easier with XSLT 2.0+, which has been around for 15 years, but many people are still using 1.0.

Comment: @MichaelKay: I am using XSLT 2.0+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can use XSLT 2.0 or higher, you could do:

```
<xsl:template match="dxrCardNumber2">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(translate(., '[]', ''), ' ')[matches(., '^\d+$')]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="dxrCardNumber2">
   <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\[([A-Z0-9]+)\]\s+\[([0-9]+)\]\s+\[([0-9]+)\]" flags="i">
     <xsl:matching-substring>
       <dxrCardNumber2><xsl:value-of select="concat(regex-group(2),' ')"/>
       <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(3)"/></dxrCardNumber2>
     </xsl:matching-substring>
     <xsl:non-matching-substring>
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </xsl:non-matching-substring>
   </xsl:analyze-string>        
</xsl:template>
```